# Tkinter: move to random position on click

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a simple tkinter game, and have run into a problem. I want to be able to move an image to a random spot on the screen when you click on it, but what I thought would work hasn't. Below is the code:

```
spr_earth=PhotoImage(file="earth.gif")
x=r.randrange(64,roomw-64)
y=r.randrange(64,roomh-64)

earth=canvas.create_image(x,y,image=spr_earth)
x1,x2,y1,y2=canvas.bbox(earth)


def click(event):
if ((event.x>x1) and (event.x<x2)) and ((event.y>y1) and (event.y<y2)):
    canvas.move(earth,r.randrange(64,roomw-64),r.randrange(64,roomh-64))

root.bind_all("<Button-1>",click)
root.mainloop()
```

I thought this would work, but it clearly doesn't. You can click on it, but it appears to teleport into space an beyond :)

I'd appreciate anyone's input on this problem. thanks

Answer (score 2):

From [reading the documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.move-method), it looks like `move` coordinates are relative to the current position.

Perhaps something like this would work (warning, this code is untested):

```
def click(event):
    if ((event.x>x1) and (event.x<x2)) and ((event.y>y1) and (event.y<y2)):
        canvas.coords(earth,(r.randrange(64,roomw-64),r.randrange(64,roomh-64)))
```

---

for what it's worth, the following simplified script seemed to work for me:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from random import randrange

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width=400,height=400)
canvas.pack()
image = tk.PhotoImage(file='mouse.gif')

def position():
    return randrange(0,400),randrange(0,400)

mouse = canvas.create_image(*position(),image=image)

def click(event):
    canvas.coords(mouse,position())

canvas.bind('<Button-1>',click)

root.mainloop()
```

(The mouse always stayed partially on the canvas).

[image]

Comment: so could I somehow use canvas.coords instead?

Comment: what does the %roomw and %roomh mean

Comment: modulus -- It's the remainder of division.  On second thought though, I don't think this works.  Coords is better ... Let me edit.

Comment: I just tried this: `def click(event):
    if ((event.x>x1) and (event.x<x2)) and ((event.y>y1) and (event.y<y2)):
  x=r.randrange(64,roomw-64)
  y=r.randrange(64,roomh-64)
  canvas.coords(earth,(x,y))` and it worked for a few clicks only, which is odd

Comment: that's pretty much what I wrote, and it still only works for a click or two. I find that quite strange

Comment: Yeah, I think that's weird too... If I get some time I might play around with it.  Otherwise, we'll need to wait for one of the experts to weigh in (@BryanOakley)

Comment: Hey mgilson, I tried your method and it works pretty good. Now I just need to add the if statements to check If the mouse is over the image, right? I tried that, and I ran into a problem. I made an event called 'pos' which used what you wrote: `return r.randrange(64,roomw-64), r.randrange(64,roomh-64)` and I added this statement to it: `if ((event.x>x1) and (event.x<x2)) and ((event.y>y1) and (event.y<y2)):`. Now, since I referenced 'event', I added event in the method parentheses [def pos(event):]. But now I have a problem: what do I put in the parentheses when calling pos()?